# How to use HTML Table as gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to fetch data from database in HTML TABLE rather than Gridview?

Comment: Do you mean to present data from database to an HTML table?

Comment: You are aware that the GridView is actually rendered as a table?

Answer (score 2):

Try using MVC3 with the razor engine instead.

Comment: I highly recommend using MVC 3

Answer (score 1):

I think you could not do that try Repeater instead
.
Here are some tutorials:

- [ASP.NET Tutorial. How to use Repeater.](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater)
- [ASP.NET - Database Connection.](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/). It provides loads of useful features and some nice styling options as well.

There are plenty of examples on their site also. Check out the [ASP.NET example](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/asp_net) as that seems to suit your tags on this question.

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is another option